# Change sphinx-build master file

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Can I tell `sphinx-build` stop looking for `index.rst`.

```
$ echo 'test' > readme.rst
$ sphinx-build -C . ./build readme.rst
```

This wil complain about a missing index file

```
master file /.../index.rst not found
```

However we could sort of fix this

```
$ ln -s readme.rst index.rst
$ sphinx-build -C . ./build readme.rst
```

This will actually build both `index.rst` and `readme.rst` and it will complain that `readme.rst` is not included in any toc tree. Which could be fixed by using `mv` instead of `ln`. However I don't want to move files around just to satisfy the wierd need for `sphinx-build` to have an index file. I also don't want to have lingering link all over the place either.

Can I change the location of the master file? Something like (which does not work):

```
$ sphinx-build -C -D 'master_file=readme.rst' . ./build
```

Or can I tell it to skip the index file all together? Something such as (which does not work):

```
$ sphinx-build -C -D 'exclude_patterns=index.rst' . ./build readme.rst
```

Or is there another way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rename your `index.rst` to `readme.rst`.

Then you may specify the [`master_doc` configuration option](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-master_doc) either in your `conf.py` and build your docs or by overriding that value in your `conf.py` on the command line when building your docs.

#### Specified in `conf.py`

```sh
$ sphinx-build . ./build
```

#### Specified on command line only

```sh
$ sphinx-build . ./build -D master_doc='master'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sphinx-build -C . ./build readme.rst -D master_doc='readme'
```

In more detail:

```
$ ls
readme.rst
$ sphinx-build -C . ./build readme.rst -D master_doc='readme'
Running Sphinx v1.8.5
making output directory...
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are specified
building [html]: 1 source files given on command line
updating environment: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] readme                                                          
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] readme                                                           
generating indices... genindex
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in build.
$ ls
build       readme.rst
```

The same thing worked for me with Sphinx 3.0.2.